# I want to complete a variable name with any disponible

Tags: c++, variables

I'm quite new to C++, and I'd want to complete a variable name for if statement that has all variables that its name starts with those words.
Such as like writing `sudo apt install libgcc*`
I'm using Visual Studio and whant to do a program that is, imagine:

```
int var1 = 1;
int var2 = 2;
int var2 = 3;
// I want to reference all variables that start with var
// For example, var references that.
tostring(var);
```

So, is there any way to do that?

Comment: _`sudo apt install libgcc*`_ What does that shell command has to do with your c++ code?? I have no clue, what you're asking about, sorry!

Comment: What would do with "all variables that its name starts with"? Show a C++ program you want to use this feature in.

Comment: Really the only way to do this is to store your "variables" in some sort of key-vaulue pair where the key is the name and the value is the value you want the variable to hold.  You can then traverse a collection of those key-value pairs and only process the "variables" where they key satisfies your condition.

Comment: It really seems you want auto-completion. `Ctrl+space` is the default shortcut of some common IDE for that.

Comment: In your edit, what do you expect the line `tostring(var);` to do? Can you show some code that would be equivalent to the behavior you want to achieve?

Comment: Variable names are vane in c++ ... There's no runtime reflection.

Comment: Are you looking for arrays? Like `int var[3]`?

Comment: "I'd want to complete a variable name for if statement that has all variables that its name starts with those words" - You may want that, but C++ doesn't work like that.

Comment: Apart from arrays or std::map this does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for that, I'll better make an array.